# Configure eclipse formatter to place the enum's semicolon on its own line

Tags: java, eclipse

Currently I have auto-formatting like this:

```
public enum EnumConstants {
    EMPTY(),
    TINY(1),
    LARGER(5),;

    EnumConstants(){

    }

    EnumConstants(Object a){

    }
    int getVal() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Which is very close to what I want. However, I want to emphasize the semicolon and I want to, among other reasons, simplify the work on git when comparing changes made to files.

Given so, I want to format the file like this:

```
public enum EnumConstants {
    EMPTY(),
    TINY(1),
    LARGER(5),
    ;

    EnumConstants(){

    }

    EnumConstants(Object a){

    }
    int getVal() {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Notice that only the semicolon changed.

What options allow that adjustment?

Comment: the best option would be to remove the last coma as it's useless and missleading. If I see something like that, I think that someone either missed an enum value or it was legacy code not properly cleaned on last edit

Comment: @jhamon That is an interesting POV. I wonder if it is the norm

Comment: @jhamon a trailing comma is common practice because it interacts nicely with VCS. Without one, every time you add a constant you have to change the line with the previous last one to add a comma. This messes with blame and can cause merge conflicts in the worst case. Also it makes it easier to reorder the lines